# How to Connect SQLite with Power Automate?

Tags: sqlite, odbc, power-automate

I want to connect Power Automate with SQLlite3? But it is not connecting although i have ODBC driver installed on my system.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to install ODBC driver for SQLite 3 from below link
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Then open the ODBC driver app in windows and add a new "User Data Source" and specify your .db file.

Then use below connection string to connect to SQLite3 from Power Automate using Open SQL connection.

DSN=your_datasource_name;Database=D:\Data\Desktop\xyz.db;